# iOS custom fonts with html tags

Tags: html, ios, fonts, uikit

Hi I need to show my labels and textviews with font style (regular, bold, italic) 
Well I figured out that using NSAttributeString I may solve this by doing:

```
 NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[@"<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    _textview_label.attributedText = attrStr;
```

in fact this will work with system font, but how can I do this using an custom font, for example MULI or another.

How can I make my application know that when I need a bold it will use `Muli Bold` font and with italic `Muli italic` and by default `Muli Regular` in the same string (label.text)?

Answer (score 0):

The string below shows text in Helvetica-bold-italic.

I don't have 'MULI' font installed, so I'm using Helvetica.

Try it.

```
<span style='font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic'>bold italic</span>
```